# SQLite merge/union/flatten subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, recursive-query, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to write some SQL code in the same vein as the "Outlandish Recursive Query" examples at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html.

In particular, I'm trying to make a prime sieve using SQL.  I tried a recursive cte with `EXCEPT` instead of union, but that is FORBIDDEN:

```
CREATE TABLE target AS SELECT 25 AS i, 100 AS n;

WITH RECURSIVE primes AS (
    SELECT
        value AS p
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(3, (SELECT target.n FROM target LIMIT 1), 2)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT
        (SELECT value FROM GENERATE_SERIES(p*p, (SELECT target.n FROM target LIMIT 1), p))
    FROM
        primes
)
```

This fails because `EXCEPT` clauses aren't allowed in recursive ctes, only `UNION` and maybe `INTERSECT`.

Anyway, I then tried the less efficient but less absurd

```
WITH multiples AS (
    SELECT
        (SELECT value AS p FROM GENERATE_SERIES(n.value*n.value, (SELECT target.n FROM target LIMIT 1), n.value))
    FROM
        GENERATE_SERIES(3, (SELECT SQRT(target.n) FROM target LIMIT 1), 2) n
)
SELECT * FROM multiples;
```

But the result is only `9, 25, 49, 81`, not `9, 15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 75, 81, 87, 93, 99, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 49, 63, 77, 91, 81, 99`

How can I merge the subquery results instead of just taking the first entries of each?

I think there's a function called `UNNEST` that does this magically in some flavors of SQL, but it is not in SQLite.  I read that SQLite doesn't actually implement arrays, which explains why `GENERATE_SERIES` can only be used as a table and `UNNEST` is missing, but I don't know much about SQL so I don't know all the implications of this.

`UNION ALL` would also work fine, except afaik it only works with one table; I can't `UNION ALL` over a correlated subquery for all rows in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Computing prime numbers *is* a resource-intensive task. Here is a brute-force approach:

```
with recursive nums(i, max_n) as (
    select 3, max(n) max_n from target
    union all
    select i + 2, max_n from nums where i < max_n
)
select n.i
from nums n
inner join target t on n.i between t.i and t.n 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from nums n1
    where n1.i < n.i and n.i % n1.i = 0
)
```

The recursive query generates all uneven numbers from 3 to the upper bound of `target`. Then, the outer query filters the list of numbers on the target range with a `join`, and uses `not exists` to ensure that the number we picked is not a multiple of a smaller number.

Ideally we would have a way to build the prime list in the recursive query, but that somehow requires re-opening the recursive CTE in the `from` clause... which most database engines currently don't support, as you are experiencing.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VI16TsT7)** - for range 25-50:

| i |
| --- |
| 29 |
| 31 |
| 37 |
| 41 |
| 43 |
| 47 |

NB: the fiddle does not support `generate_series`, but if your database does then we can shorten the query:

```
select n.i
from (select value i from generate_series(3, ( select max(n) from target ), 2 ) n
inner join target t on n.i between t.i and t.n 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from nums n1
    where n1.i < n.i and n.i % n1.i = 0
)
```

Comment: Interesting, so the `where not exists` clause is doing trial division on each number in `n`. I modified this a little, generating `nums` and `divs` (the same but only up to `sqrt(target.n)` in a cte, and it runs up to 20000 in 1 sec. I'm using a wheel based sieve that generates all coprime multiples of all numbers coprime to 6 and then excludes those from a select query, which runs in 0.01 sec. (See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hacatu/project_euler_sql/main/p10.sql). But I'm more concerned with merging correlated subqueries, since it could be useful outside of impractical exercises.